# What's the use of Malgrange preparation theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, examples, cv.complex-variables

The Malgrange preparation theorem,which is the $C^{\infty}$ version of the classical Weierstrass preparation theorem,says that if $f(t,x)$ is a $C^{\infty}$ function of $(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ near $(0,0)$ which satisfies 
$$
f=\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{t}}=\cdots =\frac{\partial^{k-1}{f}}{\partial{t^{k-1}}}=0\quad \frac{\partial^{k}{f}}{\partial{t^{k}}}\ne 0\quad\text{at}(0,0)
$$
Then there exists a factorization
$$ 
f(t,x)=c(t,x)(t^{k}+a_{k-1}(x)t^{k-1}+\cdots +a_{0}(x))
$$
where $a_j$ and $c$ are $C^{\infty}$ functions near $0$ and $(0,0)$ respectively,$c(0,0)\ne 0$ and $a_{j}(0)=0$.As a corollary, there is a division thereom just like the Weierstrass formula.However, unlike the analytic case,this factorization is not unique.The result is said to be highly non-trival even when $k=1$,the difficulty is then the zeros may be lost,For example,$t^{2}+x$ has two real zeros when $x<0$ but none when $x>0$.The proof can be seen in Theorem 7.5.6 in Hormander's The Analysis of linear partial differential operators.

My question is What's the use of Malgrange preparation theorem in mathematics?Is this a verey useful formula in analysis ? Can anyone take some examples to apply this theorem?(In hormander's book,this is used in the method of Stationary Phase).

A quick google search shows that there is also a algebraic version which can be restated as a theorem about modules over rings of smooth, real-valued germs.

Answer (score 10):

The Malgrange preparation theorem is extremely useful in singularity theory, where it can be used to prove Mather's fundamental theorem on the equivalence of infinitesimal stability and stability for $C^\infty$ mappings, and can also be used to derive the normal forms of some stable singularities. The book "Stable mappings and their singularities" by Golubitsky and Guillemin is a good reference.

Answer (score 10):

Malgrange elaborated his preparation theorem in order to prove that if $L$ is a linear differential operator with constant coefficients, then it admits a **fundamental solution**, that is a distribution $E$ such that $LE=\delta_{x=0}$. Then if $f$ is a smooth function with compact support, the equation $Lu=f$ admits the solution $u=E\star f$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I didn't know that before,by the way,the proof of this theorem(thm 7.3.10) in Hormander's book is by constructing some particular measure.Maybe that's originally from Ehrenpreis who also proved the result.

Comment: @Denis Serre Are you sure of this ? After all constant coefficients PDE are described by a polynomial with $n$ variables, a very simple type of analytic function. Why the preparation theorem, usually devised to dealing with smooth non-analytic functions satisfying a finite type assumption could be useful in that context ?

Comment: This answer refers to the Ehrenpreis-Malgrange Theorem which is very different from the Malgrange Preparation Theorem.

Comment: @SönkeHansen Actually, the Malgrange preparation theorem and the Malgrange-Ehrenpreis theorem are not unrelated. The former came as a spinoff of of Malgrange's work on the latter, as he tells us himself at the end of his book "Ideals of Differentiable Functions" (OUP, 1966). To quote, "In other words, *every linear differential operator with constant coefficients has a temperate fundamental solution* (i.e. one in $\mathscr{S}'$). This is mainly of historical interest (...). We have, however, given this here because it was the origin of a large part of the results contained in this book."

Answer (score 9):

Take $k=1$ in your statement. There are two easy cases: the first one is when $f$ is real-valued, then you have only to use the implicit function theorem to get a normal form $t+a(x)$, up to a unit (a non-vanishing factor). The next easy case is when $f$ is analytic: then again implicit function theorem for holomorphic functions, same normal form, of course with $a$ complex-valued and analytic.

What if $f$ is only $C^\infty$ and complex-valued? Malgrange preparation theorem answers precisely to this question. Same normal form with $a$ complex-valued $C^\infty$. Caveats: no uniqueness, very hard proof. A example of application: a $C^\infty$ complex valued principal-type symbol (smooth function on the cotangent bundle of a smooth manifold) can be reduced to
$$
\xi_1+iq(x_1,x',\xi').
$$
It means that this type of equation can be reduced to an evolution equation (time variable $x_1$).
Without Malgrange preparation theorem, no thorough analysis of scalar complex-valued
pseudodifferential equations of principal type in the $C^\infty $ framework.

Comment: @Bazin Thanks very much,this is very useful to me

Answer (score 4):

One use is to prove that the sheaf $\mathscr{O}_\infty$ of complex smooth functions on a smooth algebraic variety $X/\mathbb{C}$ is flat over $\mathscr{O}_X$ (the sheaf of holomorphic functions). This was for example used by Deligne [(3.2.3) b), 1] to construct filtered resolutions of the logarithmic de Rham complex.

[1] P. Deligne *Thêorie de Hodge, II*. Pub. Mat. IHES 40 (1971), pp 5-57

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the differential preparation theorem as well as its relation with distribution division problem (solved independently by Lars H\"ormander and Stanis\l aw \L ojasiewicz; a version is mentioned in Denis Serre's answer) is nicely explained by Malgrange himself in the paper MR2065138 (2006i:46039) Malgrange, Bernard(F-GREN-F) Idéaux de fonctions différentiables et division des distributions. (French) [Ideals of differentiable functions and division of distributions] With an Appendix: "Stanisław Łojasiewicz (1926–2002)''. Distributions, 1–21, Ed. Éc. Polytech., Palaiseau, 2003

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with the Bognadov-Takens bifurcation there a number of transformations, the Malgrange preparations theorems become handy.